# Как изменить базовое сообщение при отбрасывании IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, исключения

У меня есть enum, в нем просто константы, без переменных, я в контроллере перевожу строку в enum через valueOf: ProductName.valueOf(product)
И, если нет такого значения джава бросает исключение со стандартной Английской формулировкой о невалидности сообщения.
Как можно заменить эту формулировку на свою, не используя try-catch, не создавая кастомных функций и своих исключений?

Comment: Вы отбросили все возможные варианты. Мне кажется, что по-другому это сделать не получится. Вы никак не можете контролировать передачу текста сообщения в `IllegalArgumentException` при пробрасывании его в функции `valueOf()`.

Comment: Отбросил не я, а ревью)

Comment: обработать через `if-else` есть ли такой объект. если его нет -> `throw new Exception("мой текст");` это ведь не "свое исключение"))